# Cannot navigate to a sibling router

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router

My conversation-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ConversationComponent } from './conversation.component';
import { ConversationDetailComponent } from './conversation-detail/conversation-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ConversationComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'detail',
        component: ConversationDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'detail/:conversation_id',
        component: ConversationDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'add-conversation',
        component: ConversationDetailComponent,
        data: {
          addNew: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'detail'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ConversationRoutingModule { }
```

And in the conversation-detail.component.ts with router 'conversation/add-conversation':

```
this.router.navigate(['../detail'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

It just navigate to root default router and console log is nothing.

I am using angular 6.0.0 and lazy module loading.

Comment: What is `../contacts` ?? Can you share your `app-routing` file code?

Comment: @SangwinGawande Thanks, I have updated my code.

Comment: Can you try doing only `this.router.navigate(['/detail']);`

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but the same result. It seem angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17957

Comment: Yeah. Looks a critical one.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your support time. Wait for news from angular team :)